# Can't integrate FXML generated with SceneBuilder in Netbeans JavaFX project

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx-2, fxml, scenebuilder

I generated an FXML using scene builder. Now the problem is when I try to integrate it I get a bunch of exception lines. Does anyone else stumble upon this problem ?

```
Apr 23, 2012 2:33:40 AM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader logException
SEVERE: The following error occurred at line 31 in file /C:/Users/gulcoza/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Commerce/build/classes/commerce/Login.fxml[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@1d59bc95
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.javafx.main.Main.launchApp(Main.java:453)
    at com.javafx.main.Main.main(Main.java:537)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.net.URL
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at commerce.Commerce.start(Commerce.java:25)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$2$1.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.net.URL
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    ... 15 more
Java Result: 1
```

I assume that the FXML is fine, because it works to preview it from SceneBuilder. Thanks

Comment: What's at line `31` in `Login.fxml`?

Comment: @Torious <stylesheets> <url ..../> <stylesheets/>

Comment: From those exceptions, it looks like the URL at that line is incorrect. What URL does it say in `Login.fxml` at line `31`?

Comment: Is looks like version mismatch issue like in your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473074/javafx-fxml-not-working-as-scenebuilder-preview-sceencast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for my late reply.

```
  <stylesheets>
    <URL value="@style.css" />
  </stylesheets>
```

The line with the error is URL line. It is generated by SceneBuilder.

PS: Also updating the JavaFX version to 2.2+ should fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can also remove the controller from the FXML in SceneBuilder and then manually add all the fxID's that are present in the controller java file (annotated with @FXML). The fxID's still will not be recognized after you've re-added the controller class in scenebuilder, however the fxid= "fxid name" will be added to the FXML file itself so when you run the javaFX program it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, its hard to understand anything without your fxml file or code. But anyway: does this bug happens with all your projects or only with this one? If not only this - maybe you use old version of javafx sdk or some other global configurations are wrong. If only this one has this problem - try to delete component by component from your FXML file, to localize the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not how to load the FXML but this way I did that error

```
primaryStage.setTitle ("FXML TableView Example");
    primaryStage.setScene
    ((Scene) FXMLLoader.load (getClass (). GetResource ("fxml_tableview.fxml")));
    primaryStage.show();
```

That way if I run:

```
Parent FXMLLoader.load root = (getClass (). GetResource ("Prueba.fxml"));
     primaryStage.setTitle ("FXML TableView Example");
     primaryStage.setScene (new Scene (root));
     primaryStage.show ();
```

Hope this helps.