# JavaFX FXML not working same way as in SceneBuilder (sceencast)

Tags: layout, resize, javafx-2, fxml, scenebuilder

I've got this FXML that is working perfectly in SceneBuilder Preview and acts completely different on NetBeans JavaFX Sample Application (so there is nothing extra that could break it's behaviour). (see [sceencast](http://screencast.com/t/9PR9snLd))

I need that 2 TitledPanes to autoresize (half and half) according with the Window (as it works in the SceneBuilder Preview).

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="798.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="javafxapplication2.Sample">
  <children>
    <VBox id="vBox1" prefWidth="770.0" spacing="25.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="25.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="25.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="25.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="25.0">
      <children>
        <TitledPane id="titledPane1" fx:id="test" prefWidth="748.0" text="Admin" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
          <content>
            <AnchorPane id="Content" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0">
              <children>
                <TableView id="tableView1" prefWidth="718.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="14.0" />
              </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          </content>
        </TitledPane>
        <TitledPane id="titledPane2" prefWidth="748.0" text="Resellers" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
          <content>
            <AnchorPane id="Content" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="744.0">
              <children>
                <TableView id="tableView2" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="14.0" />
              </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          </content>
        </TitledPane>
      </children>
    </VBox>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SceneBuilder Preview and NetBeans JavaFX Sample Application are using different versions of JavaFX. Probably the SceneBuilder is using 2.1 and NetBeans 2.0.2. Upgrade the version of the app, either by upgrading the Java version of your machine or importing the new jfxrt.jar version to your classpath (ie. into netbeans app libraries).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can't believe this was my problem. This messed a lot my application. I have to rethink lots of nasty stuff I've improvised.